# Could an 1.5 year gap affect my application for setting foot into PhD or Job?

Tags: phd, job

I have 1.5 year time gap since I graduated from master degree (Jan 2020) and I am wondering if this could affect my current interview evolution? (Job interview).

All that time I was in the process for acquiring the certificate of proficiency in English as well as A2 certificate for German language. I was also practising on one programming language.

Furthermore, Covid-19 of course affected my job seeking due to many postponements and cancellations that I had.

Comment: It might have some effect and might need explaining. I doubt that it would lead to rejection of an otherwise strong application, particularly in these covid times.

Answer (score 3):

It won't make a lick of difference.  No-one (except a spy agency) is going to care about a 1.5 year gap in the scheme of a potential career, all the more so if it was due to COVID interruption and was spent productively.